# .Sum() method with queries

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
int sum = this.baseClass.PhoneCalls.Sum(phonecall => phonecall.Seconds);

        Show(this.baseClass.PhoneCalls
            .Where(phonecall => this.baseClass.Employees
                .Where(employee => employee.Department.Name.Equals("Finanzas"))
                .Any(employee => employee.TelephoneNumber.Equals(phonecall.DestinationNumber)));
```

Hello,

I'm trying to make a sum for the phone calls made by one specific department, but I just made to sum all the calls, without a filter for the department.

I can't figure out how to include that sum variable into the Show(), so it just sums the phonecalls from the people from that specific department.

Classes

(Employee)

```
public class Employee {

    public Employee(string name, string surname, DateTime dateOfBirth, string telephoneNumber, string email, string province, Office office) {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Email = email;
        TelephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        Province = province;
        Office = office;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public Office Office { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public int Age { get { return (DateTime.Now - DateOfBirth).Days / 365; } }

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format("[Employee: {0}]", Name);
    }
}
```

(PhoneCall)

```
public class PhoneCall {

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string SourceNumber { get; set; }    

    public string DestinationNumber { get; set; }   

    public int Seconds { get; set; } 

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format("[Phone call: from {0} to {1}]", SourceNumber, DestinationNumber);
    }
}
```

(Department)

```
public class Department {

    public Department(string name, IEnumerable<Employee> employees) {
        Name = name; 
        Employees = employees;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format("[Department: {0}]", Name);
    }
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: what is the _relation_ between `People`, `PhoneCall` and `Department`? Show us how did you define your classes.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add them. Now they're there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you're having trouble because `Any` returns `bool`.. you want to filter.. so add another condition to the `Where` then `Sum` after that:

```
Show(this.baseClass.PhoneCalls
        .Where(phonecall => this.baseClass.Employees
            .Where(employee => employee.Department.Name.Equals("Finanzas") &&
                               employee.TelephoneNumber.Equals(phonecall.DestinationNumber)))
    .Sum(phonecall => phonecall.Seconds));
```